# $\text{ran}\,N$ is closed if and only if $0$ is no limit point of $\sigma(N)$, for a normal bounded operator $N$ on a hilbert space $H$

Tags: spectral-theory, orthogonality, projection, normal-operator

This question has been asked once in this forum, but I don't understand some things in the proof of one direction. I marked them in bold:

${\Longleftarrow}:$ Let $\lambda\in\sigma(N)   $ be an isolated point in $\sigma(N)$. We will show in general that then $\text{ran} (N-\lambda I)$ is a closed space. Define $F$ as a continuous function that is 1 near $\lambda$ and $0$ on $\sigma(N)\backslash\{\lambda\}$ (for example a mollifier). So, $F$ is either 1 or 0 on the spectrum, which means that $P:=F(N) = E(\{\lambda\})$ ($E$ is the unique spectral measure of $N$ given by the spectral theorem) is an orthogonal projection. Clearly $(N-\lambda I)P=0$ because $H(z)=(z-\lambda)F(z)$ vanishes on $\sigma(N)$.

Let $Q=I-P$. Then $Q(N-\lambda I)=(N-\lambda I)$, which means that the range of $N-\lambda I$ is contained in the range of $Q$ (since the multiplication is the composition in this space). Define
\begin{align*}
        G(z) = \begin{cases} 0, & z = \lambda, \\ \frac{1-F(z)}{z-\lambda}, & z\neq \lambda.\end{cases}
    \end{align*}
Then $(z-\lambda)G(z) = 1-F(z)$, which gives
\begin{align*}
             (N-\lambda I)G(N) = Q.
    \end{align*}
So the range of $N-\lambda I$ equals the range of $Q$, which is a closed subspace (since $Q$ is also an orthogonal projection).

Comment: $F$ is a continuous function on the spectrum of $N$ (a subset of $\mathbb{C}$), but "$F(N)$" is a reference to the "continuous functional calculus" for normal operators.  It extends the more familiar interpretation of $F(N)$ when $F$ is a polynomial.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus (does not provide a definition but does mention key properties).   See also https://planetmath.org/continuousfunctionalcalculus (not the only approach, but one approach). It may be possible to find a solution that does not use this, but this may be worth learning anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this and try to understand it

Comment: @leslietownes Is it true, that $P:=F(N) = E(\{\lambda\})$, where $E$ is the unique spectral measure fo $N$ given by the spectral theorem for bounded normal operators and therefore $P$ is an orthogonal projection?